# Is there a way to plot a density function over a histogram that was plotted using the PlotRelativeFrequency() function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector of sample means and I've been tying to plot a probability histogram using hist(x) and ggplot but the bins exceed 1(which is very unusual for a probability distribution),I then used a PlotRelativeFrequency(hist(x)) function to force R to plot a histogram of probabilities,It worked! but My problem is,I  cannot plot a density function over the histogram.When I used the lines(density(x)) function it plots a density function that goes way off the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is tagged with ggplot, I'll give a ggplot answer.

To make histograms relative you have to set `aes(y = stat(density))` such that it integrates to 1. Then, you could give the `stat_function()` the relevant density function for any theoretical distribution. The downside is that you'll have to pre-compute the parameters.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(500, 10, 2))

pars <- list(mean = mean(df$x), sd = sd(df$x))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, aes(y = stat(density))) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) {dnorm(x, mean = pars$mean, sd = pars$sd)})
```

[image]

Next up, we can plot the empirical density using kernel density estimates, which does everything pretty much automatically:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, aes(y = stat(density))) +
  geom_density()
```

[image]

Lastly, you can have a look at this [stats function](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggnomics/blob/master/R/stat_theodensity.R), that essentially automates the first version. Full disclaimer: I'm the author of that github repo.

```
library(ggnomics)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, aes(y = stat(density))) +
  stat_theodensity()
```

[image]